# Deleting duplicate elements in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, duplicates

Hi and thanks for reading! I'm currently studying Generics in Java and this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I need to delete duplicate elements from an ArrayList. Currently, the ArrayList contains integers. I want to first print the original list, and then print the resulting list after removing the duplicates. This is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(1);

    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(2);

    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(3);

    removeDuplicates(list1);

      System.out.println("Original List with Duplicates: \n" + list1);
        System.out.println();
        //System.out.println("After removing duplicates: \n" + list2);

}

public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list2){


    for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++){

    //logic to remove duplicates    


    }

    return list2;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of the list? If so, do you want to keep the first, the last, or some other specific duplicate?

Comment: I want the final result to just be "1 2 3" instead of "1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3". But the order doesn't necessarily matter as long as the duplicates are gone.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the elements to the Set collection. If you want to preserve order you should use LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 1):

**Step One**

Convert your list to a set.

`Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>(list);`

**Step Two**

Convert your set back to a list.

`list = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(list));`

**Why it Works**

Sets can only contain unique elements.

Comment: I'm not really sure what a HashSet is. Is there a way to do it without one?

Comment: @user3254957 A HashSet is a really efficient Set. A Set is a collection of items that are unique.

Comment: @user3254957: When you don't know what a class is, read its documentation. That's how you'll learn. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

Convert the ArrayList to Set, maybe HashSet and then back to an ArrayList that you could sort if you want the numbers in order (the ordering in Sets are not usually not guaranteed).

```
HashSet hs<Integer> = new HashSet(list1);

ArrayList<Integer> uniqueList = Collections.sort(new ArrayList<Integer>(hs));
```

There's also various `SortedSet`, among them `TreeSet`.

Also, you can use a less error-prone `for` loop construction:

```
for (int i : uniqueList) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: ArrayList does not have a sort method

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(1);

    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(2);

    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(3);



      System.out.println("Original List with Duplicates: \n" + list1);
      System.out.println();

      list2 = removeDuplicates(list1);

      System.out.println("After removing duplicates: \n" + list2);

}

public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list2){

    ArrayList<E> usedList = new ArrayList<E>();
    ArrayList<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>();

    for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++){

        E object = list2.get(i);

        if(! usedList.contains(object))
        {
            usedList.add(object);
            newList.add(object);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
Original List with Duplicates: 
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

After removing duplicates: 
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you're working with other types (not java standard like `int`), then you have to override the `equals` method, because it's used in the `ArrayList` `contains` method.

Comment: this is theoretically correct, but unacceptably slow (complexity n^2). The algorithm gets too slow to use in practice, since it has to go through the new list element by element to know if the new item is unique or not.

Comment: @claj Yes, you're right. But i think that for learning purposes (when efficieny _usually_ isn't that important), this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: It is quite evil to teach people things that doesn't work in real life, at least not without stating that really really clearly. Your example miss that kind of warning. Also, the example is much longer than other solutions given.

Comment: Yeah I'm not too concerned with efficiency at the moment.

Comment: What if I wanted to remove everything that has duplicate elements? For example: if I add 4 and 5 to the list as individual elements, after removing all duplicate elements the output would just be "4 5" since 1,2, and 3 all have duplicate elements.

Comment: No. If you add 4 and 5 to the initial list, the output will be [1,2,3,4,5]. Test it and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list2){
    LinkedHashSet<E> dataSet = new LinkedHashSet<E>(list2.size());
    dataSet.addAll(list2);
    ArrayList<E> uniqueLists = new ArrayList<E>(dataSet.size());
    uniqueLists.addAll(dataSet);
    return uniqueLists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers so far create a new list. If you want to modify the list in place, you can iterate through the list while using an auxiliary `Set` to keep track of all elements already seen. The following works for any `List` (not just `ArrayList`) that allows elements to be removed:

```
public static <E> List<E> removeDuplicates(List<E> list){
    ListIterator<E> iter = list.listIterator();
    Set<E> seen = new HashSet<>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (!seen.add(iter.next())) {
            // element not added--must have already been seen, so remove element
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

An alternative is to dump the entire list into a `Set`, clear the list, and then add all the element of the set back into the list. Depending on the `Set` implementation, this may or may not preserve order.

```
public static <E> List<E> removeDuplicates(List<E> list){
    Set<E> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(unique);
    return list;
}
```

EDIT: If (as per your comment) you wish to completely remove elements that are not unique to start with, you can modify the first approach:

```
public static <E> List<E> removeNonUnique(List<E> list){
    Set<E> seen = new HashSet<>(); // all values seen
    Set<E> dups = new HashSet<>(); // all values seen more than once
    for (E elt : list) {
        if (!seen.add(elt)) {
            // element not added--must have already been seen, so add to dups
            dups.add(elt);
        }
    }
    // clean out the list
    list.removeAll(dups);
    return list;
}
```

Note that since we're not modifying the list during the loop, we don't need to have an explicit iterator.

Comment: Thanks for that!What if I wanted to remove everything that has duplicate elements? For example: if I add 4 and 5 to the list as individual elements, after removing all duplicate elements the output would just be "4 5" since 1,2, and 3 all have duplicate elements.

Comment: @user3254957 - I added some code to show how I would do that. I changed the method name, since it doesn't really do quite the same thing at all.